# Storing Trainable Values in TensorArray for While_loop - tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on a small Tensorflow model using Tensorflow 2.3.0. in the model I use several tf.while_loops  and TensorArray. The model is not working as expected. I tried to troubleshoot the issue but unfortunately not all Tensorflow behavior is documented and I'm not sure if there is a bug in my model or it is Tensorflow behavior I'm unaware of.  For example in my model I multiply my data with some weights inside a tf.while_loop. I then store the result in TensorArray . The TensorArray content is again used in the same fashion  until I minimize the loss to train the model.

my problem is that the model does not train as expected . I suspect that tensorflow is freezing the weights and not updating them as I would expect.

How can I make sure that the content of the last TensorArray remains trainable since it is produced using data with trainable weight variables . I'm trying to avoid the issue mentioned  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTcWi.png) but not sure if I have.

below is a simple example ( dummy model ) just to clarify what I'm doing :

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
import numpy as np


size=20
randvalues = np.random.choice(a=[0.0, 1.0], size=(size,10, 10), p=[.5, 1-.5]) 
x = tf.constant(randvalues , tf.float32) 
y = tf.constant(randvalues , tf.float32) 
init_range = np.sqrt(6.0 /20)
initial = tf.random_uniform([  10, 10 ], minval=-init_range,
                                maxval=init_range, dtype=tf.float32)
weights = tf.Variable(initial, name="testWeight1")
w1_summ = tf.summary.histogram("testWeight1" ,weights )
init_range = np.sqrt(6.0 /15)
initial2 = tf.random_uniform([  10, 5 ], minval=-init_range,
                                maxval=init_range, dtype=tf.float32)
weights_tied = tf.Variable(initial2, name="tiedWeight")
w2_summ = tf.summary.histogram("tiedWeight" ,weights_tied )




ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype = tf.float32 , size=0 , dynamic_size=True , clear_after_read=False , infer_shape=False  )
ta2 = tf.TensorArray(dtype = tf.float32 , size=0 , dynamic_size=True , clear_after_read=False , infer_shape=False  )





def condition(counter ,ta1): 
    return counter < size


def body(counter ,ta1):
    with tf.name_scope("firstloop"):
        operation1 = tf.matmul(x[counter],weights)
        operation2= tf.nn.relu(operation1)
        operation3= tf.matmul(operation2,weights_tied)
        operation4= tf.matmul(operation3,tf.transpose(weights_tied))        
        ta1 = ta1.write(counter,tf.reshape(operation4,[-1]))
        return counter +1 , ta1 

runloop , array1 = tf.while_loop(condition,body,[0 , ta ] , back_prop=True  ) 

def condition2(counter ,ta1 , array1): 
    return counter < 1


def body2(counter , ta2 ,array1 ):
    with tf.name_scope("secondloop"):
        operation = array1.stack()  
        operation4= tf.nn.relu(operation)
        ta2 = ta2.write(counter,tf.reshape(operation4,[-1]))
        return counter +1 , ta2 ,array1

runloop2 , array2 , _ = tf.while_loop(condition2,body2,[0 , ta2  ,array1] ,back_prop=True) 
predictions= array2.stack()

loss=tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=tf.reshape(predictions,[-1]), targets=tf.reshape(y,[-1]), pos_weight=1)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss) 
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=.001)  
gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
additional_summeries = [ tf.summary.histogram( "GRAD"+str(g[1]) , g[0]) for g in gvs]
opt_op= optimizer.apply_gradients(gvs) 
merge= tf.summary.merge([w2_summ , w1_summ]  + additional_summeries )
sess = tf.Session()
summ_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\Projects\\MastersEnv\\GraphAutoEncoder\\gae\\summaries', sess.graph)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for cc in range(1000) : 
    a , b, = sess.run([runloop2 , opt_op])
    c = sess.run(merge)
    summ_writer.add_summary(c,cc)
    print(cc)
    
print('done')
```

In the above example the content of `array2` should be the predictions. how can I make sure that the loops and the tensorArray did not affect the train-ability of my variables ? If what I did was incorrect. whats the best approach to achieve the same thing but keeps my result trainable.

**Update ::**

Ok , So I ran the my model for some times and monitored the loss, accuracy and other scaler metrics. And found a general trend in loss decrease and accuracy and other accuracy related metric increase. the Accuracy and loss are also inverse of each other , to my understanding this indicates that the updates are not random and the model is learning something.

Additionally I monitored the weights and gradients distributions are changing which confirms that variables are being trained.

[image]

Can you some please confirm my conclusion and understanding ?

Thanks for your help in Advance.